# Testing Ember Data - Switching to FixtureAdapter during test runs

Tags: unit-testing, ember.js

I have [an ember.js app](https://github.com/balanced/balanced-dashboard/blob/test) and I'm setting up a `DS.Store` like this ([view actual code](https://github.com/balanced/balanced-dashboard/blob/test/app/models/store.js)):

```
(function (app) {
    'use strict';

    ...

    var store = DS.Store.extend({
        revision: 12
    });

    app.Store = store;

})(window.Balanced);
```

Now I have a qunit test and in that test I would like to swap the default RESTAdapter for a FixtureAdapter so that I can setup fixtures for my models. I figure I need to write [something like this](https://github.com/balanced/balanced-dashboard/blob/test/test/models/store_test.js) but I'm not 100% sure:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    var fixtureAdapter;

    module('tests.store.module', {
            setup: function () {
                fixtureAdapter = DS.FixtureAdapter.extend({

                });
                Balanced.Store.reopen({
                    adapter: fixtureAdapter
                });

                //  TODO: how does this work?
                Balanced.Marketplace.FIXTURES = [
                    {id: 1, name: '1'},
                    {id: 2, name: 'poop'},
                    {id: 3, name: 'poop'}
                ];
            },
            teardown: function () {
                // teardown code
            }
        }
    );

    test("Marketplace query", function () {
        var marketplaces = Balanced.Marketplace.find();
        //  TODO: how do I test this?
    });
})();
```

Comment: is the reason you want to swap out the adapter to create them in memory? or that you really want the exact syntax of the FixtureAdapter? You could use the local storage adapter or just new up the objects in memory (any of these viable solutions for you?)

Comment: Maybe I have the wrong idea. All I want to do is mock away the actual HTTP calls so I can verify that the expected HTTP operations are happening in response to whatever the app is doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For my basic unit testing with jasmine I setup the store manually like so (using the local storage adapter to avoid xhr requests)

```
describe ("CodeCamp.SessionView Tests", function(){

  var get = Ember.get, set = Ember.set, sut, controller, session, store;

  beforeEach(function(){
    store = DS.Store.create({
      revision: 11,
      adapter: DS.LSAdapter.create()
    });
    sut = CodeCamp.SessionView.create();
    controller = CodeCamp.SessionController.create();
    controller.set("store", store);
    sut.set("controller", controller);
    session = CodeCamp.Session.createRecord({ id: 1, name: "First", room: "A", ratings: [], speakers: [], tags: []});
  });

  afterEach(function() {
    Ember.run(function() {
      store.destroy();
      controller.destroy();
      sut.destroy();
      session.destroy();
    });
    store = null;
    controller = null;
    sut = null;
    session = null;
  });

  it ("will create rating when form is valid", function(){
    sut.set('score', '1234');
    sut.set('feedback', 'abcd');
    sut.addRating(session);
    var ratings = CodeCamp.Session.find(1).get('ratings');
    var rating = ratings.objectAt(0);
    expect(rating.get('score')).toEqual('1234');
    expect(rating.get('feedback')).toEqual('abcd');
    expect(rating.get('session').get('id')).toEqual(1);
  });

});
```

The test above goes end-to-end for the following ember view

```
CodeCamp.SessionView = Ember.View.extend({
  templateName: 'session',
  addRating: function(event) {
    if (this.formIsValid()) {
      var rating = this.buildRatingFromInputs(event);
      this.get('controller').addRating(rating);
      this.resetForm();
    }
  },
  buildRatingFromInputs: function(session) {
    var score = this.get('score');
    var feedback = this.get('feedback');
    return CodeCamp.Rating.createRecord(
    { score: score,
      feedback: feedback,
      session: session
    });
  },
  formIsValid: function() {
    var score = this.get('score');
    var feedback = this.get('feedback');
    if (score === undefined || feedback === undefined || score.trim() === "" || feedback.trim() === "") {
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  },
  resetForm: function() {
    this.set('score', '');
    this.set('feedback', '');
  }
});
```

If you want to see this entire app in action (just a sample ember app with a few basic jasmine tests) it's on github

https://github.com/toranb/ember-code-camp/

Comment: Thanks Toran, this is a great start to reference.

Comment: for others who might follow -here is another great reference (up to date at the time I'm writing this) http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/testing-ember-apps-how-do-you-do-it/173/19